# Entity Framework Code First seeding entities having user id foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Here is my two entities and context classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Header { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser Host { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

And here is my seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
            new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(
                new ApplicationDbContext()));

        var user0 = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "User0",
            FirstName = "FirstName0",
            LastName = "LastName0",
            Email = "Email0@Example.com",
        };
        manager.Create(user0, "Password0");

        var user1 = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "User1",
            FirstName = "FirstName1",
            LastName = "LastName1",
            Email = "Email1@Example.com",
        };
        manager.Create(user1, "Password1");

        var user2 = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "User2",
            FirstName = "FirstName2",
            LastName = "LastName2",
            Email = "Email2@Example.com",
        };

        var eventObj = new Event()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Host = user0,
            Header = "Header0",
            Description = "Description0",
            Date = DateTime.Now
        };
        manager.Create(user2, "Password2");

        context.Events.AddOrUpdate(eventObj);
    }
```

When I run the command **Update-Database** in Package Manager Console, I'm getting the following result:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

What am I doing wrong? I'm working on VS 2013 Asp.net Mvc template.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what do the details in the  `EntityValidationErrors` say? post that.

Comment: - User : User name User0 is already taken. @SOfanatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my seed method and it works fine now:

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
            new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(
                context));

        var user0 = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "User0",
            FirstName = "FirstName0",
            LastName = "LastName0",
            Email = "Email0@Example.com",
        };
        manager.Create(user0, "Password0");

        var user1 = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "User1",
            FirstName = "FirstName1",
            LastName = "LastName1",
            Email = "Email1@Example.com",
        };
        manager.Create(user1, "Password1");

        var user2 = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "User2",
            FirstName = "FirstName2",
            LastName = "LastName2",
            Email = "Email2@Example.com",
        };

        var eventObj = new Event()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Host = user2,
            Header = "Header0",
            Description = "Description0",
            Date = DateTime.Now
        };

        context.Events.AddOrUpdate(eventObj);
        manager.Create(user2, "Password2");
```

Now I'm calling Create user method after adding Event entity to context.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `context` parameter into your `UserStore<ApplicationUser>` constructor (you need to use the same `DbContext` instance for your users as you use for your events later in the `Seed` method):

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
            new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(
                // new ApplicationDbContext() // <- no
                context // yes!
                ));
```

Comment: show your `UserManager` and `UserStore` code (at least enough to see what happens with a call to `Create`)

Comment: oh, try adding a `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` to your `DbContext` - not sure what your `UserManager` is doing without that...

Comment: That part is from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674760/Code-First-Migration-and-Extending-Identity-Accoun Everything works fine except seeding the Event entity.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using addorupdate in that way if the data is already there the data is just updated.

> Seed data: Override the Seed method in this class to add seed data. - The Seed method will be called after migrating to the latest version. - You can use the DbContext.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.

myContext.AddOrUpdate(c => c.FullName,
  new Customer { FullName = "Andrew Peters", CustomerNumber = 123 },
);

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it, I needed to scroll just a little more.